# Modified QEMU XML file does not appear to be used

Tags: kvm, qemu

I've created a qcow2 image snapshot of a KVM guest image. I've modified the XML file for the image to use the new snapshot file but when I halt and restart the guest, and create a file on the guest the new snapshot file is not updated. Here are the details.

(1) Create the snapshot.

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 -b /var/lib/libvirt/images/myguest.img /var/lib/libvirt/images/myguest.qcow2.snap
```

(2) Edit two lines in /etc/libvirt/qemu/myguest.xml

```
<driver name='qemu' type='qcow2' cache='none'/>
<source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/myguest.qcow2.snap'/>
```

(3) ssh to myguest and halt it.

(4) Confirm with "virsh list" that the guest is indeed no longer running."

(5) Restart the guest.

```
virsh start myguest
```

myguest.qcow2.snap was indeed created by qemu-img with an expected small size of 197K but, even if I create files in myguest the .snap file is never written to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you modify the XML file you should

```
virsh define myguest.xml
```

That will cause `libvirtd` to detect the changes so that the next `virsh start` will start up with the new values.

Comment: That did it. Thanks! Time to go read the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of editing `/etc/libvirt/qemu/myguest.xml` directly, use

```
virsh edit myguest
```

When you exit the editor, `virsh` will notify `libvirtd` that the file has been changed. The next guest restart will use the new values.

If `virsh edit` uses the "wrong" editor, remember you can set it like this

```
EDITOR=vi virsh edit myguest
```

Comment: +1.  for some things, like adding an extra disk, you don't even have to restart the VM,  BTW, another useful method is: `virsh dumpxml myguest | xml-editing-tool-of-your-choice... | virsh define /dev/stdin`.  You could use `xmlstarlet`, `xml2 | awk/sed/perl/etc | 2xml` or a custom script in perl, python, whatever (e.g. I wrote a simple perl script to add `<serial>...</serial>` tags to raw disk devices that didn't already have them).